# How to flag a question for reopening

Tags: support, status-completed, flagging

Yesterday this question ([Considering career change to patent agent/patent engineer [closed]](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/84484/considering-career-change-to-patent-agent-patent-engineer)) was closed. The question was now edited by the original author and I would like to flag it for reopening. Is this possible? If it isn't, I'd like to suggest this as a feature request.

Comment: I've cast the final reopen vote and edited the commentary out of the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, just issue a flag for a moderators attention. As ChrisF was the original moderator vote I let him issue the reopen - though you're three votes there already.

Comment: I flagged it then. Thank you Josh.